# How to load applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, war

I trying to load an applicationContext.xml from java class in a web application using

```
  ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

and

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

My question is how to load applicationContext.xml from a java class. The applicationContext.xml is WEB-INF. Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `ContextLoaderListener` in your `web.xml` file:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param> 

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then you can use the `WebApplicationContext` to load the context:

```
WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servlet.getServletContext());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Sufala A S was this helpful?

Comment: Thanks, I get it worked! refer to : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-instantiating-container-web

Comment: what is that `servlet`??

Answer (score 2):

A `ContextLoaderListener` is used when you want to load a specific context that will act as your context root. If you want to load additional contexts for whatever reason, you can define your own `ServletContextListener`, create your `ApplicationContext` instances, and put them in the `ServletContext` attributes so that they are available to the web application

```
public class AdditionalContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // destroy those contexts maybe
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ApplicationContext context = ...; // get your context
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("someContextIdentifier", context);
    }

}
```